# Get script name in OCaml?

Tags: module, ocaml, filenames

Does OCaml have a way to get the current file/module/script name? Something like:

- C/C++'s `argv[0]`
- Python's `sys.argv[0]`
- Perl/Ruby's `$0`
- Erlang's `?FILE`
- C#'s `ProgramName.Environment.CommandLine`
- Factor's `scriptname/script`
- Go's `os.Args[0]`
- Haskell's `System/getProgName`
- Java's `System.getProperty("sun.java.command").split(" ")[0]`
- Node.js's `__filename`
- [etc.](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let _ =
    let program = Sys.argv.(0) in
        print_endline ("Program: " ^ program)
```

And posted to [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptName#OCaml).

Answer (score 10):

I don't know anything about OCaml but some googling turned up

```
Sys.argv.(0)
```

See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual003.html#toc12

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are scripting in OCaml. Then Sys.argv.(0) is the easiest way to get the script name. Sys module also provides Sys.executable_name, but its semantics is slightly different:

let _ = prerr_endline Sys.executable_name; Array.iter prerr_endline Sys.argv;;

If I run the above line, putting the line in test.ml, by ocaml test.ml hello world, I have:

```
/usr/local/bin/ocaml         - executable_name
test.ml                      - argv.(0)
hello                        - argv.(1)
world                        - argv.(2)
```

So OCaml toplevel does something fancy against argv for you.

In general, obtaining the current module name in OCaml is not easy, from several reasons:

- ML modules are so flexible that they can be aliased, included into other modules, and applied to module functors.
- OCaml does not embed the module name into its object file.

One probably possible workaround is to add a variable for the module name by yourself, like:

let ml_source_name = "foobar.ml"

This definition can be probably auto inserted by some pre-processing. However, I am not sure CamlP4 can have the file name of the currently processing source file.

If your main purpose is simple scripting, then of course this pre-processing is too complicated, I am afraid.

Comment: Defining the source name may not work for my purposes. Besides printing the filename for CLI usage purposes, imagine that I want to bundle an API with a CLI. The filename can tell me whether OCaml is loading the code on its own (and therefore should run some main-like function), or whether the code is being loaded by another module, in which it should execute nothing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604201/scripted-main-in-ocaml/

Answer (score 2):

In OCaml >= 4.02.0, you can also use [`__FILE__`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL__FILE__) to get the filename of the current file, which is similar to Node's `__filename` and not the same as `Sys.argv.(0)`.